# CollapsingToolbarLayout / Toolbar margin bug

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to use in my app similar layout to @chrisbanses cheesesquare (https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).

Everything works great on Nexus 5,6. But when you test it on other devices like Samsung S6, Sony Z3 Compact the buttons from the toolbar are not visible.

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_vehicle"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

This is my layout. I can't find a way to fix this. You can try to run Cheesesquare on phone like Samsung S with 5.0.2 Android. I've also tested Sony devices. The same. Nexus phone's are OK.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

I'm using com.android.support:design:22.2.0 (the latest version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I've got confirmation. This is bug in Design Support Library 22.2.0. 
More information:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176647

If you know any workaround before Google will publish a fix I'll be greatful.

There is a workaround for the Toolbar and missing buttons problem (wrong position)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != 21) return; 

final int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
final int result = (resourceId > 0) ? getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) * 2 : 0;
final CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams params =
        (CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.topMargin -= result;
toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

EDIT:
Google updated Support Library. This bug was fixed in **22.2.1** version. Just update Support Library and use the latest version and everything will be fine.

Comment: This works but the problem is that it clears all menu items i had in my toolbar like the icon for the nav drawer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ("samsung".equals(Build.MANUFACTURER) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Toolbar toolbar = getToolbar();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        lp.topMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, -47, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

Comment: This is only for Samsung. If you check other phones it won't work - for example Sony Z3, OnePlus One. It's easy to create fix only for one one. Good news that this issue is fixed by Google and we'll see updated Support Library soon.